# MapView Still Displays Blank View

Tags: android, google-maps

I have gotten my API key and set all permissions. I have also set that it uses the Google maps library, but I still get the gray grid when I load the map layout. I also can't get the emulator to work with the coordinates. It says "Disabled Provider Network", however the coordinates work just fine when I debug on my phone.

Here is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0inWE-rpNsby-evq_ORv1bdMuhprR3R38VeZaAw"
        />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Corresponding Java File.

```
package com.example.zip.code;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;

public class OpenMap extends MapActivity  {
    private MapController mapController;
     private LocationManager locationManager;
      private String prov;
      double lat;
      double lng;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maplayout);
        //Criteria crit = new Criteria();
        //prov = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, false);
        //Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(prov);
        // Get Mapping Controllers etc
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        mapController = mapView.getController();

        // Center on Current Position
        //mapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                                                //  (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6)));
       // mapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint(1924000,-99120000));
        mapController.setZoom(11);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    }

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.mapsettings, menu);
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          // Handle item selection
          switch (item.getItemId()) {
              case R.id.zipswap:
                  swapToZip();
                  return true;
              default:
                  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
      }

      public void swapToZip(){
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
          startActivity(i);
      }
}
```

I have no idea what seems to be going wrong. I have used everything that should be required but I still get a gray grid. Do I need a separate key for debugging or something?

Comment: Do you have more than one .android folder on your computer? If so, try the other one. I found I had 2.

Comment: This is a great spot to help also: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Answer (score 0):

If you run or debug your eclipse, You should have debug Key for google maps, Here is a link that helps you to get debug API key

Check the Section 'Getting the MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate' section on

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

or

New Link path
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey

At the time of releasing the build, you must replace the existing debug API key with the API key.

Comment: I've already done all of that in the manifest. I have all Network services enabled.

Comment: Check your system's Internet Connection

Comment: Do you have all this in your manifest? <permission
        android:name="com.example.zip.code.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.zip.code.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />